# After importing sklearn, no results were generated, but I have successfully installed the scikit-learn module

Tags: python, scikit-learn

For example, set two simple outputs above and below import sklearn, but the result of the run will only be the above output.

```
print("1") 
import sklearn
print("2")
```

The console output is:

```
1

Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)
```

I can import scikit-learn without any errors, but the statements after importing it cannot be executed. Reinstalling scikit-learn after uninstalling it did not help.

Comment: Please post the console contents as text, not an image of text.  And provide *some* explanation of how it relates to your question.  (Cute avatar!)

Comment: Only sklearn or same with every module?

Comment: Only importing sklearn modules has this problem, importing other modules such as numpy will work.

Answer (score 0):

You might have incurred an error during the sklearn install. Try this code when you reinstall it:

```
try:
    import sklearn
except ImportError as e:
    print(f"ImportError: {e}")
```

Comment: After I reinstalled the scikit-learn package as you did, I executed the above statement and returned only this statement: Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

Comment: Might indicate something wrong with your Python environment or another package/module when sklearn is imported. Try running the code in a fresh new Python environment to check whether its an environment-related issue.